# Why git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey) in windows?

Tags: windows, git, github

I have simply created a repository in github. 
Using the commands I am trying to upload a project to my new repository. But giving me errors after this command:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/nafeeur10/rental.git
```

Error:

> fatal: remote origin already exists.

Then

```
git push -u origin master
```

Error:

> git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
>   and the repository exists.

What is the problem and what should I do actually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.If origin url is already added, you can use "git remote -v " to see what origin is already added.

Since you have origin already set to some url, you can update origin url using

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/nafeeur10/rental.git
```

2.You might not have permission to push to master branch. Try pushing to new develop branch.

Comment: github  https://github.com/nafeeur10/rental.git (fetch)
github  https://github.com/nafeeur10/rental.git (push)
origin  git@github.com:nafeeur10/space.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:nafeeur10/space.git (push)

These four version is coming. I want to delete space. Just want to keep rental.

Comment: try using set-url command mentioned . Let us know if it works

Answer (score 3):

> fatal: remote origin already exists.

This error message indicates remote is already configured with the same name. Either add the new remote with a different name or update the existing one.

To set new remote:

```
$ git remote set-url origin https://github.com/nafeeur10/rental.git
```

Or can update existing one:

```
git remote add origin1 git@github.com:ppreyer/first_app.git
```

Doing so, everywhere in "origin" you should replace it with "origin1". For example $ git push origin master should now be $ git push origin1 master.

Answer (score 0):

Your remote origin exists. So you are probably getting this error because you didn't initialize or reinitialize(in case of a new commit in previously existing repository) your git repository. First type command "git init". After that try this command.

`git push -u origin master`

Then you might be prompted for authentication. Provide your credentials and changes will be pushed to your remote repository.